# How to run different methods in different browsers using Selenium Webdriver?

Tags: java, selenium

I have a test case in which there are 3 methods

```
 Class
 {
   Method1();
   Method2();
   Method3()
 }
```

Now, I want to run Method1() in IE, Method2() in FF and Method3() in Chrome. I have written the code and it works pretty fine. Only problem is that it gives an error in Console "org.openqa.selenium.remote.SessionNotFoundException: Session ID is null. Using WebDriver after calling quit()?"

After Method1() gets completed, I quit driver like

```
 driver.quit();
 driver=null;
 driver = new FirefoxDriver();
```

Similarly for Chrome also after Method2() gets completed.

Can someone please guide me why I am getting this message and what's the solution ?

I don't want to use Selenium grid. Thanks

Comment: If the suggestion by @lost below did not work, you need to post way more that just "not working". See this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Not working here means getting the same error "org.openqa.selenium.remote.SessionNotFoundException: Session ID is null. Using WebDriver after calling quit()?"

Answer (score 0):

According to your explanation this is what I understood :-

1. `Method1()` is for IE
2. `Method2()` is for FF
3. `Method3()` is for chrome

Why are you ending the code with new WebDriver instantiation? Instead it makes more sense when you create a a structure like below.

```
Class {
    WebDriver driver;
    Method1() {
        driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
        //code for IE goes here
        driver.quit();
    }

    Method2() {
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        //code for FF goes here
        driver.quit();
    }

    Method3() {
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        //code for chrome goes here
        driver.quit();
    }    
}
```

Your requirement seems out of ordinary. If you want to test some code in different browsers, its better to use a framework such as TestNG/JUnit or specify different test for different browsers.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks for posting comment but I tried with your way as well but it's not working.